# Precise dynamic SVG in JavaScript for behavioural experiment

Tags: javascript, svg, dynamic

I need a set of SVG circles flickering at some frequency and phase. Let's say I have 3 SVG circles and I need them to be oscillating at 4hz and all out of phase which each other; or two in phase and the other out of phase, etc. I need to be able to control this frequency and phase in the most precise way, since I'm building a simple JS application to run it in Amazon Turks as a behavioural experiment.

My first stab would be to try out with setinterval(). However, I'm not sure this will give me the precision and cleanness I'm after. More importantly,  how could I address the phase issue with setinterval() without running into a mess of dividing cycles?

Any smart suggestion? Any library uncle Google didn't mention to me?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with "control"? If you don't mean changing it runtime I would just go for CSS3 animations (easier + a lot better performance)

Comment: use SMIL animations and the browser will ensure that precision is maintained.

Comment: Alexander, yes I need to change it in runtime. I'll have the circles to apear and disappear at different frequencies during the time of the user interaction. However, I might calculate this generate this frequencies before hand, but I'd need to change CSS dynamically anyway. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [getMilliseconds()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds) from the Date object and then use [window.requestAnimationFrame(youCallback)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

In your callback you would draw the circles and for the precise positioning you would use the current milliseconds minus the starting milliseconds, so you would do something like

```
y = 30*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*freq*(Date.now().getMilliseconds()-initialMilliseconds)/1000);
```

Comment: That seems like a place to start, thanks! 

However by oscillating I ment like "apear/disappearing" no so much to oscillate on the y axis.

Comment: Yes, you can use that too in order to determine if you'll draw your SVG circle or not. As for if you can change the CSS dynamically with Javascript, yes you can do that and if you use JQuery it is even easier. With Javascript you would do something like  document.getElementById("myobject").style.color = "red";

Comment: This was very nice and works great.

The thing is that with frequencies higher than 10hz this thing just colapses. Not really sure why. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know, it probably has to do with the maximum frames per second (FPS) rate that can be achieved.

Comment: 10 FPS is very low, dont you think?

Comment: Probably yes, but even if the refresh rate from the browser was higher you would be limited by the refresh rate of your monitor, thus aliasing comes to play.